# Is ruby 2.1.2 timeout still not thread safe?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, multithreading, timeout, sidekiq

I have 50 sidekiq threads crawling the web, and a few weeks ago the threads started hanging after about 20 minutes of running. When I do a backtrace dump, most of the threads are stuck on net/http initialize:

```
/app/vendor/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/net/http.rb:879:in `initialize'
/app/vendor/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/net/http.rb:879:in `open'
/app/vendor/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/net/http.rb:879:in `block in connect'
/app/vendor/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/timeout.rb:76:in `timeout'
/app/vendor/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/net/http.rb:878:in `connect'
/app/vendor/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/net/http.rb:863:in `do_start'
/app/vendor/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/net/http.rb:858:in `start'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/net-http-persistent-2.9.4/lib/net/http/persistent.rb:700:in `start'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/net-http-persistent-2.9.4/lib/net/http/persistent.rb:631:in `connection_for'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/net-http-persistent-2.9.4/lib/net/http/persistent.rb:994:in `request'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/mechanize-2.7.2/lib/mechanize/http/agent.rb:257:in `fetch'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/mechanize-2.7.2/lib/mechanize/http/agent.rb:974:in `response_redirect'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/mechanize-2.7.2/lib/mechanize/http/agent.rb:298:in `fetch'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/mechanize-2.7.2/lib/mechanize.rb:432:in `get'
/app/app/workers/crawl_page.rb:24:in `block in perform'
/app/vendor/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/timeout.rb:91:in `block in timeout'
/app/vendor/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/timeout.rb:35:in `block in catch'
/app/vendor/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/timeout.rb:35:in `catch'
/app/vendor/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/timeout.rb:35:in `catch'
/app/vendor/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/timeout.rb:106:in `timeout'
```

I didn't think sidekiq would get stuck on net/http because I've wrapped the entire call in a timeout: `Timeout::timeout(APP_CONFIG['crawl_page_timeout']) { @page = agent.get(url) }`

...but then I started reading some old posts about how ruby's Timeout is not thread safe: http://blog.headius.com/2008/02/rubys-threadraise-threadkill-timeoutrb.html

Is ruby's Timeout still not thread safe?

I know a lot of people write crawlers in Ruby. If Timeout isn't thread-safe, how are people writing crawlers handling the issue of net/http getting stuck?

**Update:**

I've switched to HTTPClient (which specifically says its thread safe) to replace mechanize. We appear to still be getting stuck on initializing a thread. Again, this could be due to ruby'ss Timeout not working properly, or it could be a sidekiq issue. Here's the stacktrace from the most recent hung sidekiq threads:

```
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/httpclient-2.4.0/lib/httpclient/session.rb:805:in `initialize'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/httpclient-2.4.0/lib/httpclient/session.rb:805:in `new'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/httpclient-2.4.0/lib/httpclient/session.rb:805:in `create_socket'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/httpclient-2.4.0/lib/httpclient/session.rb:752:in `block in connect'
/app/vendor/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/timeout.rb:91:in `block in timeout'
/app/vendor/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/timeout.rb:101:in `call'
/app/vendor/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/timeout.rb:101:in `timeout'
/app/vendor/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/timeout.rb:127:in `timeout'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/httpclient-2.4.0/lib/httpclient/session.rb:751:in `connect'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/httpclient-2.4.0/lib/httpclient/session.rb:609:in `query'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/httpclient-2.4.0/lib/httpclient/session.rb:164:in `query'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/httpclient-2.4.0/lib/httpclient.rb:1087:in `do_get_block'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/newrelic_rpm-3.9.2.239/lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/httpclient.rb:34:in `block in do_get_block_with_newrelic'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/newrelic_rpm-3.9.2.239/lib/new_relic/agent/cross_app_tracing.rb:43:in `tl_trace_http_request'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/newrelic_rpm-3.9.2.239/lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/httpclient.rb:33:in `do_get_block_with_newrelic'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/httpclient-2.4.0/lib/httpclient.rb:891:in `block in do_request'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/httpclient-2.4.0/lib/httpclient.rb:985:in `protect_keep_alive_disconnected'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/httpclient-2.4.0/lib/httpclient.rb:890:in `do_request'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/httpclient-2.4.0/lib/httpclient.rb:963:in `follow_redirect'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/httpclient-2.4.0/lib/httpclient.rb:776:in `request'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/httpclient-2.4.0/lib/httpclient.rb:677:in `get'
/app/app/ohm_models/queued_page.rb:20:in `run_crawl'
```

Comment: Guess what, exactly the same thing happened to me this morning. All crawlers stuck in the http method.

Comment: Wow, interesting. Any of your gems just update?

Comment: Nope. We are having this like every 2 months. The problem is, all other workers are stuck as well in the http process then. Quite bad as we have mission critical workers that really may not get stuck.

Comment: You're having this every 2 months? Does that mean this has happened before with your crawler? Have you found fixes before or has it started working again at some point and then breaks after another 2 months?

Comment: Can't find anything more recent than 2012, but the issue may be with Mechanize: https://github.com/sparklemotion/mechanize/issues/256

Are you using Mechanize also @Hendrik?

Comment: nope, we have been using Polipus as a crawler. It happens every now and then. Can't really say :(.

Answer (score 4):

Correct, it is still not safe to use `Timeout` in Ruby code, unless you know *exactly* what is happening within that block (which includes what any C code might be doing). I have personally observed catastrophic things happening in connection pools because of this.

You *may* be able to get away with rescuing errors and retrying, but if you're unlucky your process might get wedged and require a restart.

If you fork to create new processes, you can kill those safely if they run long (or use [`timeout(1)`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/timeout) because they don't have any way to corrupt your parent process.

> I know a lot of people write crawlers in Ruby. If Timeout isn't thread-safe, how are people writing crawlers handling the issue of net/http getting stuck?

Do you have a specific example of one that works?

Comment: Any recommendations on net requests? I read something on io.select but curious if there are others.