# Ruby http not threadsafe. Hangs at TCPSocket

Tags: ruby, multithreading

We are having a multi thread environment with several workers. From time to time all threads start hanging and do not proceeed. I nailed the problem down to this line:

https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/ruby_2_1/lib/net/http.rb#L878

Somebody had a similar issue before:
[Is ruby 2.1.2 timeout still not thread safe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25803089/is-ruby-2-1-2-timeout-still-not-thread-safe#comment40438901_25803089)

```
/app/vendor/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/net/http.rb:879:in `initialize'
/app/vendor/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/net/http.rb:879:in `open'
/app/vendor/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/net/http.rb:879:in `block in connect'
/app/vendor/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/timeout.rb:76:in `timeout'
/app/vendor/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/net/http.rb:878:in `connect'
/app/vendor/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/net/http.rb:863:in `do_start'
/app/vendor/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/net/http.rb:858:in `start'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/net-http-persistent-2.9.4/lib/net/http/persistent.rb:700:in `start'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/net-http-persistent-2.9.4/lib/net/http/persistent.rb:631:in `connection_for'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/net-http-persistent-2.9.4/lib/net/http/persistent.rb:994:in `request'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/mechanize-2.7.2/lib/mechanize/http/agent.rb:257:in `fetch'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/mechanize-2.7.2/lib/mechanize/http/agent.rb:974:in `response_redirect'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/mechanize-2.7.2/lib/mechanize/http/agent.rb:298:in `fetch'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/mechanize-2.7.2/lib/mechanize.rb:432:in `get'
/app/app/workers/crawl_page.rb:24:in `block in perform'
/app/vendor/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/timeout.rb:91:in `block in timeout'
/app/vendor/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/timeout.rb:35:in `block in catch'
/app/vendor/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/timeout.rb:35:in `catch'
/app/vendor/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/timeout.rb:35:in `catch'
/app/vendor/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/timeout.rb:106:in `timeout'
```

Could switching to jRuby be of any help?

Thanks!

Comment: You need to post some code, otherwise we can't guess what you're doing.

Comment: Not so much answering your question but might help: I use [Typhoeus](https://github.com/typhoeus/typhoeus) for concurrent HTTP requests. It's quite nice.